# Dask Array + hdf5 read performance

Tags: dask

I have a large number of large integer arrays stored in hdf5-formatted files. I find that representing these data as a dask array (as opposed to a list of `h5py.File` objects) is convenient for indexing the data but loading slices of the data from disk is very slow.

Here's an example where `dsets` is a list of `h5py.File` objects and `x` is a `dask.array` constructed from those `h5py.File` objects. The chunking of the dask array matches the chunking of the `h5py.File` objects.

```
# Index h5py objects individually
In [68]: %%time
    ...: tmp = [d[0,0,0] for d in dsets];
    ...:
CPU times: user 23.6 ms, sys: 3.97 ms, total: 27.6 ms
Wall time: 26.8 ms

# Index dask array
In [69]: %%time
    ...: tmp = x[:,0,0,0].compute()
    ...:
CPU times: user 2.72 s, sys: 187 ms, total: 2.9 s
Wall time: 2.87 s
```

What explains the 100x difference in time to load the same data? And is there anything I can do to bring the load time down in dask?

Edit: Here's a [repo](https://github.com/d-v-b/dask_hdf5_testing/blob/master/dask_hdf5_testing.ipynb) I made with a jupyter notebook that saves some fake data to disk as `*.h5 files` and then compares the loading performance with raw `h5py` or `dask` (with chunking matched). In these tests, I find that loading data with `h5py` in a loop is 8-10x faster than the equivalent operation in `dask`.

Answer (score 0):

Poor read performance on HDF5 files is usually due to a mismatch between how your file is chunked and how your dask.array is chunked.

For example in an extreme situation if your HDF5 file is chunked by row and your dask.array reads in chunks by column then *every* chunk reads the entire file, which can easily result in a 100x slowdown.

So you should check the chunking of your h5py.Dataset object

```
>>> d.chunks
(100, 100, 100)
```

And you should align your from_array call to these chunks

```
>>> x = da.from_array(x, chunks=(100, 100, 100))
```

Or, if those chunks are smaller than is optimal, then you should try to design your chunksize to be an integer multiple in each dimension

```
>>> x = da.from_array(x, chunks=(100, 200, 300))
```

If your dataset is not chunked

```
>>> d.chunks
None
```

Then your dataset is arranged in C-ordering and you should avoid chunking in the latter dimensions

```
>>> x = da.from_array(x, chunks=(5, None, None))
```

You should choose chunk sizes large enough to hide the overhead of task scheduling.  Dask imposes an overhead of a few hundred microseconds per chunk.  If your chunks are small then this overhead can dominate.  I generally shoot for chunks around 100MB in size, although this varies strongly by application.

Comment: I thought chunking would be the issue, so I explicitly set the `dask` chunks to match the `hdf5` chunks... 

Today I did some more testing with synthetic data. The synthetic data has the same size, datatype, and chunking as my real data, and I find that slicing the data with `dask` (with matched chunk sizes) takes 8x longer than slicing the data with `h5py` in a loop. I can post the code I used for testing if you want to give it a shot -- It's a bit long so I'd need to edit my original question.

Comment: If you're able to produce a small [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then that is always appreciated for any StackOverflow question.

Comment: I edited my question to include a link to an mcve in a github repo (there's a fair bit of boilerplate so I didn't copy+paste the code into my question directly)

Comment: I suspect that your chunk size is far too small

Comment: On your suggestion I played around with the chunk size: 

At maximum chunk size (1 chunk / file), `dask` and looped `h5py` perform identically. But, as the chunk size drops, `dask` performance worsens while `h5py` performance is constant. Any idea why this is the case?